# How can I add a route in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to map a new route after I commit a new object to db. So for example if i enter object with name "**Test**" I would like to have a new route immediately, to resolve "**Test.aspx**".

I tried

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(obj.NameUrl, obj.NameUrl + extension, new { controller = "per", action = "Index", name = obj.NameUrl });
```

in controller but it does not work (no error, just probably not right time in life cycle?). Same code works in `Application_Start()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid registering routes dynamically. The following static route in your `Application_Start` should be able to handle your scenario of having dynamic route parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "page",
    "{name}.aspx",
    new { controller = "per", action = "index" },
    new { name = @"[a-z0-9]+" }
);
```

and if the extension has to be dynamic as well:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "page",
    "{name}.{extension}",
    new { controller = "per", action = "index" },
    new { name = @"[a-z0-9]+", extension = @"[a-z]{3,4}" }
);
```

and then you could have the Index action to handle requests to this route:

```
public class PerController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string name, string extension) 
    {
        ...    
    }
}
```

and if you want to generate a link to this action:

```
@Html.RouteLink("go to foo", "page", new { name = "foo", extension = "aspx" })
```

Comment: why should i avoid registering routes dynamically, can it not be done?

Comment: @Spikolynn, you should avoid it because that's not how the routing system was intended to be used.

Comment: If it was not intended it should not be possible, but I'll accept your answer and solve problems this particular solution causes with wildcard matching. Thanks!